# Postgres Insert N Rows in a Loop for All Values in a Selected Column

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have users stored as

```
select * from users_t where user_name like 'ABC%';

id   user_name  
1    ABC1
2    ABC2
..   ..
```

Now I need to loop through all `user_name`'s and make that number of INSERTs into a different table, `RECALLS_T`. All the other columns are hard-coded constants that I define.

Assume the following table, with a Sequence called `RECALLS_T_ID_SEQ` on the ID:

```
id  created_by_user_name  field1   field2
1   ABC1                  Const1   Const2
2   ABC2                  Const1   Const2
..   ..                   ..       ..
```

How do I insert these in a Postgres loop?

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION** Also, what if I need to insert X (say 5) Recalls for each User entry? Suppose it's not a 1:1 mapping, but 5:1, where 5 is a hard-coded loop number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `select` in the `insert` statement:

```
insert into recalls_t (created_by_user_name, field1, field2)
select user_name, 'Const1', 'Const2'
from users_t 
where user_name like 'ABC%';
```

Use the function [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to insert more than one row for each entry from `users_t`. I have added the column `step` to illustrate this:

```
insert into recalls_t (created_by_user_name, field1, field2, step)
select user_name, 'Const1', 'Const2', step
from users_t 
cross join generate_series(1, 3) as step
where user_name like 'ABC%'
returning *

 id | created_by_user_name | field1 | field2 | step 
----+----------------------+--------+--------+------
  1 | ABC1                 | Const1 | Const2 |    1
  2 | ABC2                 | Const1 | Const2 |    1
  3 | ABC1                 | Const1 | Const2 |    2
  4 | ABC2                 | Const1 | Const2 |    2
  5 | ABC1                 | Const1 | Const2 |    3
  6 | ABC2                 | Const1 | Const2 |    3
(6 rows)
```

Live demo in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=be5f77e028dace9e13f15c2489daa923)

Comment: Thanks; also, what if I need to insert X (say 5) Recalls for each User entry? Suppose it's not a 1:1 mapping, but 5:1, where 5 is a hard-coded loop number.